# Swift formatting a string to a certain length

Tags: swift

I have a series of string that I need to print on 1 line.

```
var qty: Int = 1
var name: "Book"
var price: 13.50
```

I need each to have blank space appended to them so they are a certain length or have characters removed if they are too long. For the qty id like it to be a length of 3, name 30 and price 8

Format should be

```
1   Book                             13.50
```

Comment: Can you give an example? Also, more info would be helpful. Are you trying to show on the screen and using spaces to adjust the layout, or trying to store in a DB somewhere? What is the purpose of appending spaces?

Comment: I am sending the data to a printer and I need it formatted correctly. The correct spacing would look like 1   Book                             13.50. They should have the spaces on the right except for price should have spaces on the left

Comment: What if `price` has length more than 8, like `123456789.00`? Should it be `12345678`?

Comment: Yes, it should be shortened to 12345678

Comment: you can create a `character` array of length (3+30+8 = 41) and fill it with your values as: `qty` starting from index 0, `name` or `name[0...29]`(if length is greater than 30) from index 30 and the rest with `price` , starting from index 33 (truncating if larger than 8)

Comment: could you give an example of implementing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a much better, Swift-like solution:

```
String(qty).stringByPaddingToLength(3, withString: " ", startingAtIndex: 0)

name.stringByPaddingToLength(30, withString: " ", startingAtIndex: 0)

String(price).stringByPaddingToLength(8, withString: " ", startingAtIndex: 0)
```

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1416395-stringbypaddingtolength?language=objc):

> Returns a new string formed from the receiver by either removing characters from the end, or by appending as many occurrences as necessary of a given pad string.

So that's what you need.

The usage can be something as this:

```
let output = String(qty).stringByPaddingToLength(3, withString: " ", startingAtIndex: 0) + name.stringByPaddingToLength(30, withString: " ", startingAtIndex: 0) + String(price).stringByPaddingToLength(8, withString: " ", startingAtIndex: 0)
```

**UPDATE**:

In order to pad to the right:

```
let p = String(price)
"".stringByPaddingToLength(8 - p.characters.count, withString: " ", startingAtIndex: 0) + p
```

Comment: For the price how would you add the padding to the front in a swift way?

Comment: @SeanCook I have updated my answer, please check again.

Comment: Lovely answer for its time, but may be worth updating, as five years later we now have `price.padding(toLength: 8, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)`

Comment: @RayToal I haven't worked with Swift for over 4 years.

Comment: Hehe I know, I have PHP answers from like 10 years ago floating around on this site. Just dropping notes for folks that land here from Google :) Cheers.